# Picasso not loading all images

Tags: android, android-viewpager, picasso

i have been using Picasso to load my images from drawable and all works fine except that the 3rd image keeps missing and i get a blank screen instead. after a while however the image loads. i am unable to understand why this delay occurs for this image.Any help and explanation is appreciated.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);

      viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
       final ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    Button yourButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_previous);
    yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(getItem(-1), true); //getItem(-1) for prev
        }
        protected int getItem(int i) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             return viewPager.getCurrentItem() + i;
        }
    });

    Button nextButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_next);
    nextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(getItem(+1), true); //getItem(-1) for prev
        }
        protected int getItem(int i) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             return viewPager.getCurrentItem() + i;
        }
    });

  facebookButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fb);
    facebookButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                //Write file
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);     




                String filename = "bitmap.png";
                FileOutputStream stream = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

                //Cleanup
                stream.close();
                bmp.recycle();

                //Pop intent
                Intent in1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FacebookUpload.class);
                in1.putExtra("image", filename);
                startActivity(in1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    Button btnrand = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btnrand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        View view = (View) viewPager.findViewWithTag("myview" + viewPager.getCurrentItem());
        Log.d("Inside rand", "i am here");
        try{
        //You can use any view of your View instead of TextView
        Random rand = new Random();
        int rndInt = rand.nextInt(141) + 1;
        String drawableName = "c"+ rndInt;
        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(drawableName, "drawable",  getPackageName());
        ((ImageView) view).setImageResource(resID);



        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
  }

    });



  }



  class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

         public int[] mImages = new int[] {

            R.drawable.c1 ,
            R.drawable.c2 ,
            R.drawable.c3 ,
            R.drawable.c4 ,
            R.drawable.c5 ,
            R.drawable.c6 ,
            R.drawable.c7 ,
            R.drawable.c8 ,
            R.drawable.c9 ,

            R.drawable.c11 ,
            R.drawable.c12 ,
            R.drawable.c13 ,
            R.drawable.c14 ,
            R.drawable.c15 ,
            R.drawable.c16 ,
            R.drawable.c17 ,
            R.drawable.c18 ,
            R.drawable.c19 ,
            R.drawable.c20 ,
            R.drawable.c21 ,
            R.drawable.c22 ,
            R.drawable.c23 ,
            R.drawable.c24 ,
            R.drawable.c25 ,
            R.drawable.c26 ,
            R.drawable.c27 ,
            R.drawable.c28 ,
            R.drawable.c29 ,
            R.drawable.c30 ,
            R.drawable.c31 ,
            R.drawable.c32 ,
            R.drawable.c33 ,
            R.drawable.c34 ,
            R.drawable.c35 ,
            R.drawable.c36 ,
            R.drawable.c37 ,
            R.drawable.c38 ,
            R.drawable.c39 ,
            R.drawable.c40 ,
            R.drawable.c41 ,
            R.drawable.c42 ,
            R.drawable.c43 ,
            R.drawable.c44 ,
            R.drawable.c45 ,
            R.drawable.c46 ,
            R.drawable.c47 ,
            R.drawable.c48 ,
            R.drawable.c49 ,
            R.drawable.c50 ,
            R.drawable.c51 ,
            R.drawable.c52 ,
            R.drawable.c53 ,
            R.drawable.c54 ,
            R.drawable.c55 ,
            R.drawable.c56 ,
            R.drawable.c57 ,
            R.drawable.c58 ,
            R.drawable.c59 ,
            R.drawable.c60 ,
            R.drawable.c61 ,
            R.drawable.c62 ,
            R.drawable.c63 ,
            R.drawable.c64 ,
            R.drawable.c65 ,
            R.drawable.c66 ,
            R.drawable.c67 ,
            R.drawable.c68 ,
            R.drawable.c69 ,
            R.drawable.c70 ,
            R.drawable.c71 ,
            R.drawable.c72 ,
            R.drawable.c73 ,
            R.drawable.c74 ,
            R.drawable.c75 ,
            R.drawable.c76 ,
            R.drawable.c77 ,
            R.drawable.c78 ,
            R.drawable.c79 ,
            R.drawable.c80 ,
            R.drawable.c81 ,
            R.drawable.c82 ,
            R.drawable.c83 ,
            R.drawable.c84 ,
            R.drawable.c85 ,
            R.drawable.c86 ,
            R.drawable.c87 ,
            R.drawable.c88 ,
            R.drawable.c89 ,
            R.drawable.c90 ,
            R.drawable.c91 ,
            R.drawable.c92 ,
            R.drawable.c93 ,
            R.drawable.c94 ,
            R.drawable.c95 ,
            R.drawable.c96 ,
            R.drawable.c97 ,
            R.drawable.c98 ,
            R.drawable.c99 ,
            R.drawable.c100 ,
            R.drawable.c101 ,
            R.drawable.c102 ,

            R.drawable.c104 ,
            R.drawable.c105 ,
            R.drawable.c106 ,
            R.drawable.c107 ,
            R.drawable.c108 ,
            R.drawable.c109 ,
            R.drawable.c110 ,
            R.drawable.c111 ,
            R.drawable.c112 ,
            R.drawable.c113 ,
            R.drawable.c114 ,
            R.drawable.c115 ,
            R.drawable.c116 ,
            R.drawable.c117 ,
            R.drawable.c118 ,
            R.drawable.c119 ,
            R.drawable.c120 ,
            R.drawable.c121 ,
            R.drawable.c122 ,
            R.drawable.c123 ,
            R.drawable.c124 ,
            R.drawable.c125 ,
            R.drawable.c126 ,
            R.drawable.c127 ,
            R.drawable.c128 ,
            R.drawable.c129 ,
            R.drawable.c130 ,
            R.drawable.c131 ,
            R.drawable.c132 ,
            R.drawable.c133 ,
            R.drawable.c134 ,
            R.drawable.c135 ,
            R.drawable.c136 ,
            R.drawable.c137 ,
            R.drawable.c138 ,
            R.drawable.c139 ,
            R.drawable.c140 ,
            R.drawable.c141 


        };

         @Override
            public int getCount() {
              return mImages.length;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
              return view == ((ImageView) object);
            }

            @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
                 Context context =getApplicationContext();
              final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
              int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
                  R.dimen.padding_medium);
              imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
              imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

              Picasso.with(context).load(mImages[position]).resize(350, 350)
                .centerCrop().into(imageView); // use ImageView
              ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
              imageView.setTag("myview" + position);

              return imageView;
            }


            @Override
            public void destroyItem(View container, int position,
                    Object object) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ((ViewPager) container).removeView (viewPager.getChildAt(position));
            }


  }

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = (View) viewPager.findViewWithTag("myview" + viewPager.getCurrentItem());
    super.onDestroy();
    ((ImageView) view).setImageDrawable(null);
}





}
```

this is my code

Comment: Is there any reason to use Picasso to load image from drawable ?

Comment: if you are facing the issue for one specific image, compare that image with other images by considering the image size and resolution

Comment: Please check your third image if other images are show perfectly then your code is ok so some problem in your third image.

Comment: well it because i get an out of memory error wen i do otherwise, with picasso this error goes n so does the 3rd image @Haresh Chhelana

Comment: n the 3rd image is OK i mean it shows perfectly OK without using Picasso, n the issue is that if i remove this 3rd image the 4th which comes up to the 3rd place disappears again, is it the slot which is unlucky, i dunno what is wrong @Haresh Chhelana